# Find a center of a cross in point-cloud

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, filtering, point-cloud-library

I have a point cloud of a cross made from two cylinders taken from the top. I don't know how to determine the center point of crossed elements located on the top edge of the highest cylinder?

I am not so good in Python scripting yet, and discovered 'PyntCloud' library several days ago. My knowledge was enough to cut the point-cloud taken from Intel Real-Sense camera from background (surrounding) with help of bounding box and curvature. I tried to simplify the point cloud with voxel grid, but now I am not sure if it may help me to find the center.

[output.ply](https://ufile.io/nyeyf) - PLY used in the code

[Screen.png](https://ufile.io/w1q1d) - Screenshot with marked central points

The piece of code is taken from Jupyter Notebook:

```
import numpy as np
from pyntcloud import PyntCloud

#Cropping everything that doesn't fit the curvature of shapes:
cropped_input = PyntCloud.from_file('C:\Python37\PC\output.ply')
k_neighbors = cropped_input.get_neighbors(k=1000)
ev = cropped_input.add_scalar_field("eigen_values", k_neighbors=k_neighbors)
cropped_input.add_scalar_field("curvature", ev=ev)
curvature = cropped_input.points["curvature(1001)"]
cropped_input.points = cropped_input.points[curvature > curvature.mean()]
cropped_input.to_file("C:\Python37\PC\simplified_cloud.ply")
cropped_input.plot()
#print(cropped_input)

#Use voxel grid to reduce number of points
cropped_input = PyntCloud.from_file('C:\Python37\PC\simplified_cloud.ply')
voxelgrid_id = cropped_input.add_structure("voxelgrid", n_x=30, n_y=30, n_z=30)
new_cloud = cropped_input.get_sample("voxelgrid_nearest", voxelgrid_id=voxelgrid_id, as_PyntCloud=True)
new_cloud.plot()
#print(new_cloud)
```

I expect receiving the coordinates of the center point, or an index of the point taken from point-cloud's list.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you actually tried reading the [docs](https://pyntcloud.readthedocs.io/)? If you had, you would know that `PyntCloud` class has an attribute `centroid`, which is exactly what you want. https://pyntcloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PyntCloud.html?highlight=centroid

Comment: @kanstar, thank you for the response. Yes I am familiar with 'centroid' attribute. It is not the way how to solve this, because the point cloud is not symmetrical so 'centroid' gives me a point in the center of the point cloud, not the cross. Here is an example (point cloud view from the top [link](https://ufile.io/b7ks7) and in a viewer [link](https://ufile.io/akm1q) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, 'centroid' was not a solution here because the cross was not symmetrical. 
The solution was to work with numpy library and determined a zone of the cylinders cross in relation to density of the points which were taken from numpy.histogram along each axis and created a filter, based on these values. Then the point-cloud was cropped so from the top the figure looked like rectangle (and was almost symmetrical). Only then I used a mask (numpy.isin) and determined what is the coordinates and index of the closest point to the 'centroid'.